# Kmeans cluster validation when I have labeled test data

Tags: python, k-means, unsupervised-learning, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to implement the **unsupervised k-means algorithm** for **sentiment analysis** of **imdb movie dataset** created by stanford.
The **steps** that I followed is :
1) **Load** the comments
2) Apply **tokenization** and **stemmetion** ,use **tf-idf algo** to create **tfidf matrix**.
3) Use **k-means algo** to divide the data into **2** clusters.

**My problem is how do I validate the the clusters**
I have **labeled test data.** I want to check if all the **negative** examples go in **one cluster** and all the **positive** examples go in **another cluster.**

For this I used the scikits **predict()** command. But the parameters that need to be provided to the **predict()** command should be **same** as the parameters of **fit()** command. But as **tfidf matrix** that is passed has the **dimensions** dependent on the **data** passed.

Comment: If you are just looking how to compare two clusterings (which can tell you how good is your clustering), you could use Rand index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index

One implementation is in scikit: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html

Comment: as a follow up to Antonio's answer, here is a good ipython notebook about unsupervides learning and different metrics/algo`s - https://mlcourse.ai/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter_english/topic07_unsupervised/topic7_pca_clustering.ipynb?flush_cache=true

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the **same dimension** for both training & testing set, you need apply your fit on the **training set** with you *tokenization*, **tf-idf** etc..
You need to apply same treatments as you do on training, on the testing set and then this will be okay :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus_train = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.'
]
corpus_test = [
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus_train)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

# Returns
['document', 'first', 'is', 'second', 'the', 'this']
```

So your training set looks like this :

```
print(X_train.toarray())
# Returns
[[1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [2 0 1 1 1 1]]

print(X_train.shape)
# Returns
(2, 6)
```

Then just transform your testing set with the **same** vectorizer :

```
X_test = vectorizer.transform(corpus_test)
print(X_test.toarray())
# Returns 
[[0 0 1 0 1 1]
[1 1 1 0 1 1]]

print(X_test.shape)
# Returns
(2, 6)
```

So you get your dimension of 6 (the number of features) for **both** training & testing set :)